# pip install numpy exits build with error but installs anyway

Tags: numpy, pip, raspberry-pi, fedora, lapack

I want to install numpy in my virtualenv on a raspberry-pi with fedora30 and python 3.7.3. I type `pip install numpy`, and after a while it produces a huge error message part of which seems to be lapack/blas related, while still installing some kind of numpy anyway. I'm unsure whether I can trust any numpy results in this case and would like advice on making the build errors go away. The build reports a fatal error among others when including `sys/endian.h`.

I installed the same system packages that I usually install on x64 computers with fedora30, where I usually get `pip install numpy` to run without problems. Doing it on a raspberry is new for me.

I tried to look for a package that provides `endian.h`: `dnf provides endian.h`, `dnf provides sys/endian.h` with no luck.

Running `pip install numpy` in my virtualenv results in a very large error message on stderr, and the following text on stdout:

```
    Collecting numpy
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/d6/be8f975f5322336f62371c9abeb936d592c98c047ad63035f1b38ae08efe/numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4MB)
    Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
      Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
      Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): still running...
      Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): still running...
    ...
      Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): still running...
      Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
      Running setup.py clean for numpy
    Failed to build numpy
    Installing collected packages: numpy
        Running setup.py install for numpy: started
        Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
    ...
        Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
        Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'done'
    Successfully installed numpy-1.17.3
```

The error message is 189352 bytes long, of which I hope to convey relevant info below:

```
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /home/examiner/projects/rekenlab_test/venv/rekenlab/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uke3fxog/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uke3fxog/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-q3wtyuey --python-tag cp37
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-uke3fxog/numpy/
      Complete output (2777 lines):
      Running from numpy source directory.
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/home/examiner/projects/rekenlab_test/venv/rekenlab/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      blis_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries blis not found in ['/home/examiner/projects/rekenlab_test/venv/rekenlab/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE

    ...

      /bin/sh: svnversion: command not found

    ...

      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /home/examiner/projects/rekenlab_test/venv/rekenlab/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /home/examiner/projects/rekenlab_test/venv/rekenlab/lib

    ...

      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/
      
        NOT AVAILABLE

    ...

      Could not locate executable g95
      customize PathScaleFCompiler
      Could not locate executable pathf95
      customize NAGFORCompiler
      Could not locate executable nagfor
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
      C compiler: gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC

    ...

      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/home/examiner/installed/python3.7.3/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c'
      gcc: _configtest.c
      _configtest.c:1:10: fatal error: sys/endian.h: No such file or directory
          1 | #include <sys/endian.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      C compiler: gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC

    ...

      _configtest.c:1:10: fatal error: emmintrin.h: No such file or directory
          1 | #include <emmintrin.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ...
      numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/f2c_blas.c: In function ‘zgemm_’:
      numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/f2c_blas.c:15670:20: warning: variable ‘ncola’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
      15670 |     static integer ncola;
            |                    ^~~~~
      gcc: numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/f2c_config.c
      gcc: numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/f2c.c
      error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/home/examiner/installed/python3.7.3/usr/local/include/python3.7m -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.7/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.7/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/f2c_d_lapack.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/f2c_d_lapack.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/f2c_d_lapack.o.d" failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /home/examiner/projects/rekenlab_test/venv/rekenlab/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uke3fxog/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uke3fxog/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-uke3fxog/numpy
      Complete output (10 lines):
      Running from numpy source directory.

      `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

        - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
        - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                            files that aren't checked into the git repo)

      Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).

      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
```

The `pip` statement seems to have installed something which seems to behave like it could be numpy though:

```
    $ python
    Python 3.7.3 (default, Oct 15 2019, 15:38:35) 
    [GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> a = np.array((1,2,3))
    >>> a + 1
    array([2, 3, 4])
```

Question: What did pip end up installing if its own build failed? Can I rely on numpy results in this state? What can I do to make the build error go away?

I installed the same system packages that I usually install on x64 computers, but maybe the raspberry-pi needs other packages to be installed explicitly?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `pip uninstall -y numpy`, then `pip install numpy --index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple/`

Comment: Hi hoefling, Typing that second statement returns the following text:

`Looking in indexes: https://www.piwheels.org/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy`

Comment: What does `python -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_supported; print(get_supported()[0])"` output?

Comment: @hoefling The output reads: `('cp37', 'cp37m', 'manylinux2014_aarch64')`